# Can websockets connect and send data to another local process running on a non http port?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm working on a solution that requires a webpage to print raw data onto a connected printer.  One option is to send the data to the printer through a process, running on the same machine as the browser.  The process listens on a specific port and forwards the data from the browser to the printer.

Is it possible to send data from a webpage to another listening process using Websockets?

Comment: The answer is - yes (the external process should run websockets server internally). Also you can possibly convert `raw` data into printable view just in the browser and send it to printer in standard way. This would be more user-friedly.

Comment: Thanks.  What do you mean by converting the "raw" data into printable view?  I was under the impression that printing raw from a browser was impossible?

Comment: Every raw data can be represented in a human readable view - at least, you are going to print this data from external process, so you know how it should be translated from the raw representation into printable, and possibly have already done this for the external process. So just move this logic into the browser, and you'll get an ordinary web-page built from underlying raw data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Websockets can send to any port, not just port 80. But unfortunately Websockets don't transport raw data. Before the connection is established, a Websocket handshake is performed, which also includes a 32-bit masking key which is XORed with the data stream from the client. That data-stream is also framed by some additional bytes. Details can be found [in the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).

This unfortunately means that a Websocket client can not communicate with a service which does not support the Websocket protocol. So you will need a middleware which accepts the users websocket connection, unpacks the data stream and forwards it to the printer.

One such middleware is [Websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify).